# How to change the input method of the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

passwd
            
So I want to change it.
Use POST method instead of using input form.
(Passwd are posted from another program)
How to change it
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dotpJ.png)
Change the form into POST(Passwd is being sented from another program by post)

Comment: Your question is super vague. Show us some code and your setup.

Comment: <div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">passwd</div>
   <input type="password" id="pwd" value="" class="form-control" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){submit.click()}"/> Here is the code

Comment: Yes. I think a hallmark of a good question is that it makes it as easy as possible for other people to help you. Communicating clearly what you are trying to accomplish and sharing your code will help with this.

Comment: Put it in your answer with the markdowns please.

Comment: What does it mean that it comes from the other program, and how?

Comment: Program will sent passwd to the site by POST

Comment: `<form action="http://localhost/sssss" method="POST">Your inout in this form</form>` -> for html. Try at here [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)    

If you are using jquery for this -> add `method: 'POST'` to request.

Comment: Please provide more details. Your question is not explaining itself.